# Calculate new column with aggregate amount

Tags: powerbi, dax, calculated-columns

I have a dataset like this:

| Contract | KPI | Contract Extension | Date Start | Contract End Date | Amount Purchased | New ID Contract | New Amount Purchased |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID 1 | A | No | 01/01/2023 | 01/05/2023 | 1000 | ID 1, ID 2, ID 3 | 1600 |
| ID 1 | B | No | 01/01/2023 | 01/05/2023 | 1000 | ID 1, ID 2, ID 3 | 1600 |
| ID 2 | A | ID 1 | 01/03/2023 | 01/05/2023 | 500 | ID 1, ID 2, ID 3 | 1600 |
| ID 2 | B | ID 1 | 01/03/2023 | 01/05/2023 | 500 | ID 1, ID 2, ID 3 | 1600 |
| ID 3 | A | ID 2 | 01/04/2023 | 01/05/2023 | 100 | ID 1, ID 2, ID 3 | 1600 |
| ID 4 | A | NO | 01/01/2023 | 01/07/2023 | 2000 | ID 4, ID 5 | 2250 |
| ID 5 | A | ID 4 | 01/03/2023 | 01/07/2023 | 250 | ID 4, ID 5 | 2250 |
| ID 6 | A | No | 01/02/2023 | 01/08/2023 | 1200 | ID 6 | 1200 |

For each Contract ID there is a total SMS purchased (Amount Purchased).
Each contract can be extended by increasing the number of SMS purchased. My goal would be to calculate the "New ID Contract" and "New Amount Purchased" columns.

For example: contract ID 3 is the extension of contract ID 2, which in turn is the extension of id 1. So the aggregate total is 1600 for these three contracts (1000+500+100).
When "Contract Extension" is populated with NO, it means that the contract in question is not an extension of another. When it is populated instead, the ID of the extended contract is indicated

So I should calculate the aggregate total for the shared contracts in the "New Amount Purchased" column and the shared contract IDs on "New ID Contract"

I wouldn't know how to set the code, so I have no attempt to show. I hope a solution is possible.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can utilize the "Parent and Child functions" in dax to help in this scenario.
[Understanding functions for parent-child hierarchies in DAX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/understanding-functions-for-parent-child-hierarchies-in-dax).

Create the following Calculated Columns in order (4 in total).

```
// Need this one to replace "No" in [Contract Extension]
Parent Contract =
  IF([Contract Extension] = "No", BLANK(), [Contract Extension])


// Need this for the PATH
Contract Path =
  PATH( Contract[Contract], Contract[Parent Contract] )


New Amount Purchased = 
  var p1 = PATHITEM([Contract Path], 1)
  var tbl = SUMMARIZECOLUMNS('Contract'[Contract Path], 'Contract'[Amount Purchased])
  return SUMX(
    tbl,
    IF(PATHCONTAINS([Contract Path], p1), [Amount Purchased])
  )


New ID Contract = 
  var p1 = PATHITEM([Contract Path], 1)
  var tbl = SUMMARIZECOLUMNS('Contract'[Contract Path])
  var pMax = MAXX(
    tbl,
    IF(PATHCONTAINS([Contract Path], p1), [Contract Path])
  )
  return SUBSTITUTE(pMax, "|", ", ")
```

[image]

Comment: Okay thanks, having duplicate rows in the table maybe interferes with the formula... It gives me a circular dependency error
I try to adapt the table in the question

Comment: Duplicate rows should not interfere with this approach. I've updated the answer above, the last two now use `SUMX` and `MAXX` - hopefully this will resolve the circular dependency. If not, which other calculated columns do you have on this table?

Comment: I'm trying to apply the code on the example table, but it gives me incorrect values in the New Purchased Amount column and in the New Contract ID column.... Maybe I did something wrong or is it giving you the correct values?

Comment: You updated the question with a new `KPI` column?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I inserted it to have evidence of the duplication of lines

Comment: Updated answer for `New Amount Purchased`

Comment: Ok, the New Amount Purchased column works correctly... The New ID contract column however does not report the aggregate values (ID 1, ID 2, ID 3 or ID4,ID 5) for each row, but a sort of cumulative

Comment: This is what I get: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5gnS.png What do you get?

Comment: This is my result
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXdlL.png

Comment: Share the formula for that column

Comment: This is the formula:

New ID Contract = 
  var p1 = PATHITEM([Contract Path], 1)
  var pMax = MAXX(
    ALL(Tabella[Contract]),
    IF(PATHCONTAINS(Tabella[Contract Path], p1), [Contract Path])
  )
  return SUBSTITUTE(pMax, "|", ", ")

Comment: Updated answer for `New ID Contract`